# Understanding if(!x) and it's purpose

Tags: php, if-statement

```
x = 1 

if(x) {
 x equals true
}
```

but what happens when you put the ! infront:

```
if(!x) { 
x equals ? 
}
```

I see it being used lots in tutorials I read and felt I understood it. But I saw it today and it confused me again.

What does it do?
What is it's purpose? why would you use it?

Comment: It means "if x is not true, execute these statements".

Comment: `!` means `not`. So `not true - false`, `not false - true`. if I don't mistake, in `c` language `0 is false` and `whatever is true`. In JS `1 is not 0` so its `true`. `true is converted to 1` so its `true` again...

Comment: you should have done some google before asking.

Comment: Which language? The behaviour of `!` can be changed in some. This is not answerable without a language tag.

Comment: Did you try `x = 17;` in the first line?

Comment: The first thing I do is google search, stack overflow is a last option for me. It amazes me that you can just decide what I've been doing before I ask a question on here. I don't get the need for your comment it's a genuine question for me

Comment: Dude, tag the language. Pretty please, with sugar on top.

Comment: Well thanks to everyone who has tried to help me and I genuinely mean that, I appreciate it. Unfortunately I can no longer post so I will no longer use stack overflow. Just really really hope the guys who can't get through the day without down-voting. Continue to enjoy themselves. For me I asked genuine questions, that as a beginner I didn't understand. No one says what your doing wrong, just down voting and assuming that people are being lazy because they don't have the knowledge you have. Well your mission was a success, I hope you enjoy it. Meanwhile I'm a beginner banned for a question

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark merely means `not` that is a boolean negation, so

```
if(!x)
{
    (not x) is true, which means x is false
}
```

For ordinal types of `x` that means `x == 0`, for pointers `x == NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This means if `x==0`  or `x== false` or `not x` as where `!x`